# reactstrap fieldset legend not square show

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I would like to use `BootStrap4` with my `Reactjs`. After install it, css of `btn btn-primay` works fine. However, I notice that square of the `fieldset` is gone. I have checked with [demo](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/form/)

To repeat my case here are my snippets.

`index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "f1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@amcharts/amcharts3-react": "^3.1.0",
    "ajv": "^6.5.0",
    "amcharts3": "^3.21.12",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "react": "^16.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "reactstrap": "^6.0.1",
    "recharts": "^1.0.0-beta.10",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-form": "^7.2.3",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

`login.js`
render(){
    const {handleSubmit} = this.props;

```
return(
  <Fragment>
    <a href="/"><img src="tokamak-model.png"/></a>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Authentication</legend>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Username</td>
          <Field
            name="userid"
            component={this.renderField}
            placeholder="User ID"
            autocomplete="username"
            type="text"
          />
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Password</td>
          <Field
            name="password"
            component={this.renderField}
            placeholder="Password"
            autocomplete="current-password"
            type="password"
          />
        </tr>
      </table>
      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </fieldset>
    </form>
  </Fragment>
)
```

}

**Update:**
The original without bootstrap
[image: without bootstrap]

The new one with bootstrap

[image: with bootstrap]

**Update2:**
Try make my own class in `my-fieldset`
`<fieldset className='my-fieldset'>`
And put this to the `css`

```
.my-fieldset{
  border: 3px solid;
}
```

But legend is sticking to the left

**Question:**
Is it possible to bring square frame of `fieldset` back and still get benefit of bootstrap?

Comment: what does square frame of fieldset means ? you want to remove the border radius for input fields ?

Comment: @johnsam I have updated my question. Since I don't know the technical term of it. I might confuse you at first time. Sorry. I am now searching for class and css key: property to adjust it.

Answer (score 2):

After 2 hours(including before posting my question) searching over the Internet I just found 2 lines of code that answers to my question

1. Define my own class in `fieldset` and `legend`
2. `legend` uses `margin` and `width`
3. `field-set` uses  `border`

`css`

```
.login-legend{
  margin: 20px;
  width: 155px;
}

.my-fieldset{
  border: 3px solid;
}
```